# Can you have many integrations for a single function? (sorry if the terminology is wrong)

Tags: integration, derivatives, constants

Forgive me for the amateur question (first time here), but it's bugging me!

OK, for example, integrating $\dfrac{1}{5x}$ would yield what?
$\dfrac{\ln(5x)}{5} +C$ OR $\dfrac{\ln(x)}{5} +C$ ? Both of these when differentiated form $\dfrac{1}{5x}$.

And if you say that you must take the constant out, why shouldn't you do the same here then?
integration of $\dfrac{1}{(5x+3)} = \dfrac{1}{5} \ln(5x+3)+C$ rather than
$ \dfrac{1}{5} \ln(x+\dfrac35)+C$
And for both examples, each integral is fundamentally different, one cannot be simplified to reach the other one. Check by substituting values of $x$ into both.

If somehow both are right, which do you choose if you are asked to write it out in terms of $x$ and $C$. (not defining the constant of integration).

On Wikipedia it does state that the constant of integration can be different and so you can have many 'anti derivatives' for a function (not really sure what that means), but in an A level text book, they just have one answer with 'C'.
So does this mean $\dfrac{1}{5x}$ and $\dfrac{1}{(5x+3)}$ have two (or more) anti derivatives?

So my question really becomes, how do you reach the *simplest* anti derivative possible, if that is what is required by the textbook.

Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: A function can have infinitely many anti derivatives, but they all would differ only by constants.

Comment: Note that $\ln(5x) = \ln(x) + \ln(5)$

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions you mention actually differ only by a constant. Note that $\ln(5x)/5+C=\ln(x)/5+(\ln(5)/5+C)=\ln(x)/5+D$. They both have the same derivative and are both anti derivatives of $1/5x$.

If you choose initial conditions, say demanding that the anti derivative satisfies $F(1/5)=0$, and you work out the correct constant, then you will get the same result despite the different appearance.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

All integrands of a function differ by a constant, i.e. if you have $f_1,f_2$ such that $f_1' = f_2' = f$, then $f_1=f_2 + C$ for some constant $C$.

In your examples:

---

The first example: $$f_1(x) = \frac15 \ln(5x) = \frac{1}{5}(\ln 5 + \ln x) = \frac15\ln 5 + \frac15\ln x=\frac{1}{5}\ln 5 + f_2(x),$$ meaning that the two functions differ only by a constant, that constant being $\frac{\ln 5}{5}$.

The second example:

$$\frac{1}{5}\ln{(x+\frac35)} = \frac15 \ln(\frac15(5x+3)) = \frac15\cdot \ln\frac15 + \frac15\cdot \ln (3x+5)$$ so again, the two functions differ by a constant.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TejasMenon You are welcome. Remember to vote up all useful answers and accept the most appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first example,
$$ \ln(5x) = \ln 5 + \ln x$$
so
$$ \frac{\ln(5x)}5 +C = \frac{\ln x+\ln 5}5 +C = \frac{\ln x}5+ \color{green}{\frac{\ln 5}5 +C}$$
and the green part becomes a new constant:
$$ \frac{\ln(5x)}5 +C = \frac{\ln x}5+ \color{green}{C}$$
The indefinite integral is not a single function, but rather a family of functions differing by (any) constant.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!